# Fastreport VCL 6.8 Text in crosstab value field giving error

Tags: delphi, crosstab, vcl, fastreport

I want to add a text field in a crosstab value field but getting error as below

> "Variant or safe array index out of bound".

What is the solution. it is working in my old application compiled with vcl 5 but gives error when compiled with vcl 6

Error is displayed when report is run

Comment: Edit you question to add the code around where you get the error.

Comment: There is no code in report

Comment: No code? Where is you error popping up? Isn't it when you run your application? Run it under debugger, it will stop on the error (Exception?) and show you the offending line. Show the code around that line.

Comment: This is the complete error while debugging

First chance exception at $751344C2. Exception class EVariantBadIndexError with message 'Variant or safe array index out of bounds'. Process BM.exe (5336)

error is in fastscript source file

fs_iinterpreter.pas

Comment: OK, and what is the code in fs_interpreter.pas around the line of error?

Comment: Ok run in debug mode again and it took me to System.variants.pas line 726 
this is what the line says

VAR_BADINDEX:      raise EVariantBadIndexError.Create(SVarArrayBounds);

Comment: You have to look at the call stack to know where the error really has. Put a break point on the line  raise EVariantBadIndexError.Create(SVarArrayBounds);  and run again. Look at the call stack to find the first function you wrote. Probably this line is where the error is. Maybe, edit your question to put the call stack and your source code around the line where the error originate. I must say that I have no knowledge of FastReport. What I say is how I would find the source of a similar problem.

Comment: Attach your report template here or send it to support@fast-report.com